# Why when getting all the materials to a List all the items are null ? And how to change object position while fading in/out?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveNavi : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject rig_f_middle;
    public float speed;
    public float distanceFromTarget;
    public static bool naviChildOfHand = false;
    public GameObject naviParent;
    public MeshRenderer[] materialsToFade;

    private List<Material> materials = new List<Material>();

    private void Start()
    {
        foreach(MeshRenderer meshrend in materialsToFade)
        {
            materials.Add(meshrend.GetComponent<Material>());
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (IKControl.startMovingNAVI == true)
        {
            var v = rig_f_middle.transform.position - transform.position;
            if (v.magnitude < distanceFromTarget)
            {
                naviChildOfHand = true;
                StartCoroutine(FadeTo(materials, 0, 0.2f));
                this.enabled = false;
                return;
            }
            Vector3 moveDir = v.normalized;
            transform.position += moveDir * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

    }

    IEnumerator FadeTo(List<Material> materials, float targetOpacity, float duration)
    {
        foreach (Material mat in materials)
        {
            // Cache the current color of the material, and its initiql opacity.
            Color color = mat.color;
            float startOpacity = color.a;

            // Track how many seconds we've been fading.
            float t = 0;

            while (t < duration)
            {
                // Step the fade forward one frame.
                t += Time.deltaTime;
                // Turn the time into an interpolation factor between 0 and 1.
                float blend = Mathf.Clamp01(t / duration);

                // Blend to the corresponding opacity between start & target.
                color.a = Mathf.Lerp(startOpacity, targetOpacity, blend);

                // Apply the resulting color to the material.
                mat.color = color;

                // Wait one frame, and repeat.
                yield return null;
            }

            StartCoroutine(FadeTo(materials, 1, 0.2f));

            if (targetOpacity == 1)
            {
                //MaterialExtensions.ToOpaqueMode(material);

            }

            if (targetOpacity == 0)
            {

            }
        }
    }

    private void ChangeChild()
    {
        var parent = GameObject.Find("Navi Parent");
        transform.parent = parent.transform;
        transform.localPosition = parent.transform.localPosition;
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.001f, 0.001f, 0.001f);
    }
}
```

In materialsToFade there are 6 mesh renderer then in the Start I'm getting the materials from each mesh renderer and it to the List materials but then all the items in materials are null.

Example of object with mesh renderer and material :

[image: Mesh renderer with material]

Another problem is how can I make that while the transform get fade out alpha is 0 and before it's starting fade in back to 1 to make the ChangeChild ?

There is a very small limited time to do it but I want that when transform alpha is 0 ChangeChild then fade in back to 1 and make as quick as possible so the player will not notice the switch.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to get the materials as a component when they are not a component, they are a reference variable. Try this instead.

```
foreach(MeshRenderer meshrend in materialsToFade)
{
    materials.Add(meshrend.material);
}
```

As for changing the child when faded out before fading in, just call ChangeChild immediately before you call StartCoroutine(FadeTo(materials, 1, 0.2f));